# How to select specific item in a "foreach" loop PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying display items from a table, then add the specific item clicked on, to a whole new table... It either ends up being ALL items get added... or ONLY the last item gets added. I don't quite understand how to select the specific item clicked on... to use... all inputs will be sanitized first... just would like to get a skeleton laid out first.

```
if (isset($_GET['page_no']) && $_GET['page_no']!="") {
    $page_no = $_GET['page_no'];
    } else {
        $page_no = 1;
        }

$total_records_per_page = 25;
$offset = ($page_no-1) * $total_records_per_page;
$previous_page = $page_no - 1;
$next_page = $page_no + 1;
$adjacents = "2";


$result_count = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) As total_records FROM items")->fetch();



$total_records = $result_count['total_records'];
$total_no_of_pages = ceil($total_records / $total_records_per_page);
$second_last = $total_no_of_pages - 1; // total pages minus 1


$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM items LIMIT ?, ?");
$result->execute([$offset, $total_records_per_page]);
$item = $result->fetchALL();



    
foreach ($item as $row){
     $value = $row['Sku'];
    echo "<tr>
 <td id='catalogimage'>".$row['Image']."</td>
 <td>".$row['Name']."</td>
 <td>".$row['Price']."</td>
  <td><form method='post'><select name='quantity' id='quantity'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
        <option value='5'>5</option>
        <option value='6'>6</option>
        <option value='7'>7</option>
        <option value='8'>8</option>
        <option value='9'>9</option>
        <option value='10'>10</option>
        <option value='11'>11</option>
        <option value='12'>12</option>
        <option value='13'>13</option>
        <option value='14'>14</option>
        <option value='15'>15</option>
        <option value='16'>16</option>
        <option value='17'>17</option>
        <option value='18'>18</option>
        <option value='19'>19</option>
        <option value='20'>20</option>
        <option value='21'>21</option>
        <option value='22'>22</option>
        <option value='23'>23</option>
        <option value='24'>24</option>
        <option value='25'>25</option>
        <option value='26'>26</option>
        <option value='27'>27</option>
        <option value='28'>28</option>
        <option value='29'>29</option>
        <option value='30'>30</option>
        <option value='31'>31</option>
        <option value='32'>32</option>
        <option value='33'>33</option>
        <option value='34'>34</option>
        <option value='35'>35</option>
        <option value='36'>36</option>
        <option value='37'>37</option>
        <option value='38'>38</option>
        <option value='39'>39</option>
        
        </select></td>
 <td><input type='submit' class='add_2_cart' value='Add To Cart' name='add'></form></td>
 </tr>";

        }
        
        

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    
        if($_SESSION['user'] == 'guest') {
            header("Refresh: 0 url = account.php");
        }elseif ($_SESSION['user'] != 'guest' && $_SESSION['userid'] != 2) {
    
    
$itemsku = $row['Sku'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$prices = $row['Price'];
$uid = $_SESSION['userid'];

            echo'<script>window.alert("Added Item To Cart: '.$row['Name'].'")</script>';
            $additem = "INSERT INTO cart (Sku, quantity, price, userid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $item = $conn->prepare($additem);
            $item->execute([$value, $quantity, $prices, $uid]);
        
                        }
```

update:

This did fix the issue...
putting each item into a new GET form, to be sent out to a hidden page. Which redirects back to the catalog page once an item is added.

```
 <td id='catalogimage'>".$row['Image']."</td><input type='hidden' value='".$row['Sku']."' name='addsku'>
 <td>".$row['Name']."</td><input type='hidden' value='".$row['Name']."' name='addname'>
 <td>".$row['Price']."</td><input type='hidden' value='".$row['Price']."' name='addprice'>
 
        <input type='hidden' value='".$_SESSION['userid']."' name='addid'>
 <td><input type='submit' class='add_2_cart' value='Sign In To Buy' name='add'></form></td>
 </tr>
```

Then the hidden file comprises of this:

```
$itemsku = $_GET['addsku'];
$prices = $_GET['addprice'];
$uid = $_GET['addid'];

        
            $additem = "INSERT INTO cart (sku, price, userid) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            $item = $conn->prepare($additem);
            $item->execute([$itemsku, $prices, $uid]);
            header('Location: catalog');
```

Comment: Your code to add the item to a new table is after the table has been displayed - at that point, there's nothing in `$row` any more. If you "view source" in your browser, you'll see that. What you need to do is to surround each of your items with `<form>` tags and submit each item to a short piece of PHP which will get the information from that specific item (so you'll need to have all of it in there, perhaps using some hidden fields) and submit it to the new table.

Comment: I don't know, I can't read that. Edit your original question where you can format the code so it's readable.

Comment: Please learn the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) with `FormData`, instead of using old school form submission.